# What is the Apache Storm alternative in AWS managed services?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, apache-storm

I am looking for an alternative AWS service to cater to Apache storm capability
any recommendations, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS offers [EMRs](https://aws.amazon.com/emr) to work with big data pipelines. EMR provides Apache Spark and Apache Flink as managed services, that are Apache storm alternatives. If you must use Apache Storm - there is no such managed service in AWS, but you can use managed Kubernetes service (EKS) and install Storm on top of it.